# Create live preview of form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multistep form, and am trying to create a live preview of values entered into various inputs, text areas and radio buttons.

So far i have the form built and have some success using the following

.js

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    $("#preview").append($("input[type='text']").val());
});
```

.html

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

This works for the first input however the second input repeats the first input's value.

I was going to go thru and make a jquery call for each elements id, but is there another way to use classes or .next etc. I would like if preferable to have the inputs label repeated then a colon then the value. So in .html Is this possible.

```
<div id="preview">
    <div>Input Label: Input Value</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple

```
$('.input').keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.'+$this.attr('id')+'').html($this.val());
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mYjrn/1/)**

Comment: That's cool, perhaps you can improve it even further by caching `$(this)` since you're calling it multiple times.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Updated the answer based on your suggestion :)

Comment: That is too slick. Thanks for the response shaved a couple of hard hours off my night.

Comment: I added a class of css value of display:none; to the divs and then changed the jquery to this to have the elements and labels show up only if there is something in the input. `$('.input').keyup(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').html($this.val());
     if (!$('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').text().trim().length) {
      $('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').parent().css("display", "none");
     } else {
      $('.' + $this.attr('id') + '').parent().css("display", "block");
     }
    });` Makes for a clean preview area. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Because your ***appending*** the values.  if you don't want to preserve the text then use

.text() or .html()

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    $("#preview").html($("input[type='text']").val());
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/98jgt/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some particular element to put the content in, you can change your row to this:

```
<div id="preview">
    <div>Input Label: <span id="val"></span></div>
</div>
```

Then with your jQuery you can target the #val

However, you'll still want to actually replace the value... not append to it, so use something like this:

```
$("#val").html($("input[type='text']").val());
```

> Note the use of `html()` instead of `append()`