# Create Live Preview of Form Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to re-create something similar to [Create live preview of form inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876797/create-live-preview-of-form-inputs)

I am trying to create a live preview of values entered into various form inputs (text areas, radio buttons, dropdown menus, image uploads etc).

I've tried using the code snippet provided in the aforementioned post but it doesn't seem to be working for me at all.

```
    /* script */

            <script>
          $(".import").keyup(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.' + $this.attr("id") + '').html($this.val());
          });
    </script> 

/* html output */
    <div id="preview">
          <div>Input 4: <span class="acf-field_60734728ddf2f"></span></div>
    </div>

/* form code */
    
    <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-60734728ddf2f is-required -r0" style="width: 50%; min-height: 98px;" data-name="actor_name_first" data-type="text" data-key="field_60734728ddf2f" data-required="1" data-width="50">
      <div class="acf-label">
        <label for="acf-field_60734728ddf2f">First Name <span class="acf-required">*</span></label></div>
      <div class="acf-input">
        <div class="acf-input-wrap"><input type="text" id="acf-field_60734728ddf2f" class="import import" name="acf[field_60734728ddf2f]" required="required"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am getting 1 error in the console:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(".import")', '$' is undefined)
```

This is a WordPress website running Elementor so I wondered if it was some sort of conflict and how I would fix that?

Comment: You need to import `jquery` to be able to use the js code above.

Comment: Wordpress templates that include jQuery usually use `jQuery.noConflict()` so try wrapping what you have shown in `jQuery(function($){ /* your code */})`

Comment: @charlietfl that worked, thanks! Bonus points if you could now help me achieve this with a form on the page and the live preview of the form inputs showing up within an iframe on the page?

Comment: If you have a follow up question you can search the website for answers, or ask a new question. Only one topic per question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728921/change-text-within-iframe-on-keyup-event

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this in the vanilla javascript:

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  paragraph.innerHTML = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input class='input' type='text'>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//it is necessary to check that jquery 
//<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//was called earlier
<script>
  //and put in document ready
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".import").keyup(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $('.' + $this.attr("id") + '').html($this.val());
    });
  });        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Wordpress templates that include jQuery usually use
> jQuery.noConflict() so try wrapping what you have shown in
> jQuery(function($){ /* your code */}) – @charlietfl

This now works, thank you!

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".import").keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("." + $this.attr("id") + "").html($this.val());
        });
     });
});
</script>
```