# Change text within iframe on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have a piece of code from [Create Live Preview of Form Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718065/create-live-preview-of-form-input) which works perfectly to update a bit of text which was input into a form on the page, but I would like to tweak it slightly so that the form input updates the text inside of an iframe instead of the text on the same page.

```
/* Script */   
     <script>
        jQuery(function($){
                          $( document ).ready(function() {
                                        $(".import").keyup(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $("."+ $this.attr("id") + "").html($this.val());
              });
                         });
                        });
        </script>

/* Form Input */
    
    <div class="acf-field acf-field-text acf-field-60734728ddf2f is-required -r0" style="width: 50%; min-height: 98px;" data-name="actor_name_first" data-type="text" data-key="field_60734728ddf2f" data-required="1" data-width="50">
      <div class="acf-label">
        <label for="acf-field_60734728ddf2f">First Name <span class="acf-required">*</span></label></div>
      <div class="acf-input">
        <div class="acf-input-wrap"><input type="text" id="acf-field_60734728ddf2f" class="import import" name="acf[field_60734728ddf2f]" required="required"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

/* iframe */
<iframe src="URL" sandbox="allow-scripts" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="700px" ></iframe>

/* Page Content */
<div class="title acf-field_60734728ddf2f"></div>
```

I'm assuming its just some tweak to the current script so that it looks inside the iframe rather than the page the iframe is embedded on?

Edit: Sorry for the bump, still stuck on this! Any help or alternative methods are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Depends entirely on the nature of the iframe URL.  If it's another domain that you don't control, you won't be able to modify the embedded document at all.

Comment: @James The URL is a subdomain of the domain name, but I can change that if necessary